# Does infinite union of subsets generated by an injective function cover the whole image?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $B \subset A$ and $f: A \rightarrow B$ be injective. A lemma used in Schroeder-Bernstein theorem says that there exists $h: A\rightarrow B$ which is a bijection.

The proof uses a construction $$C=\bigcup_{n\geq 0} f^n(A-B),$$
with $f^0 = \mathrm{id}_A$ and $f^n(x) = f(f^{n-1}(x))$.

Interestingly, because of injectivity of $f$, all terms of the infinite union are mutually disjoint and partition $C$. The first term is just $A-B$, then the second $f(A-B)$ is a subset of $B$, then third is another subset of $B$ and so on. This way consecutive terms eat up more and more of $B$, but it is not clear to me that they should get "smaller". Also, $f(C) = C \cup (A-B)$ so we have a "Hilbert hotel" situation where application of $f$ corresponds to a shift of an infinite sequence of sets.

My question is: is $C = A$? The proof of the lemma is agnostic to this, because it constructs another function that is piecewise defined on $C$ and $A-C$. I tried to construct a counter-example (i.e. a situation where $C \neq A$) on $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [-1, 1]$ by use of point discontinuities, but failed.

Perhaps to clarify: I understand well that an infinite union can in general converge. I have a picture in my head similar to the one in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3281555). My concern is specifically about unions generated by repeated application of an injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible for $C\ne A$. Suppose you have an $A$, $B$, and $f$ already. Let $D$ be any set disjoint from $A$, and let $g$ be any bijection from $D$ to itself. Then write $A' = A\cup D$ and $B'=B\cup D$, and extend $f$ to an injection $f'\colon A'\to B'$ by having $f'=f$ on $A$ while $f'=g$ on $D$. You'll find that $C$ is unchanged, and in particular is disjoint from $D$ and hence not equal to $A'$.

For a concrete example, let $A=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ and $B=\{1,2,\dots\}$ (so that $A-B=\{0\}$), and let $f(a) = a$ if $a$ is odd while $f(a)=a+2$ if $a$ is even. Then $f^{(n)}(A-B) = \{2n\}$, and $C=\{0,2,4,\dots\}$.

Comment: I like the example because it shattered my intuition that the set has to be uncountable! Thank you.